# Как работает DHT?

Tags: nat, torrent

Этот вопрос - один из "да знаю я как... а как, на самом деле?" Вот [здесь](https://distributedlab.com/blog/ru/description-of-dht) хорошо (на мой взгляд) описан принцип работы DHT. Если мне известен сетевой адрес одного из участников сети, я могу стать ещё одним её участником и радостно раздавать исключительно законный, само собой, контент.

И это исключительно понятно до тех пор, пока не оказывается, что участники сети находятся один в Урюпинске, другой в Магадане. Они оба сидят за динамическим NAT и видеть друг друга на прямую не способны абсолютно.

Внимание, вопрос: как мой Transmission (bitTorrent-клиент) поддерживает активность при том, что я удалил все сведения о внешних трекерах? Как мы видим друг друга? Я даже не знаю тех, кто помогает мне прямо сейчас.

Comment: В Transmission специально встроен адрес одного из участников сети — `dht.transmissionbt.com` — а дальше через него можно найти других участников, у которых отсутствует NAT или которые способны пробить NAT

Comment: В других торрент-клиентах тоже есть встроенные адреса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181301

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, в комментариях дали исчерпывающий ответ:

> В Transmission специально встроен адрес одного из участников сети —
> [dht.transmissionbt.com](https://dht.transmissionbt.com) — а дальше через него можно найти других
> участников, у которых отсутствует NAT или которые способны пробить
> NAT. В других торрент-клиентах тоже есть встроенные адреса
> [stackoverflow.com/questions/1181301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181301) – [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/706520)

Comment: С удовольствием! Только ответ не в ответах, а в комментариях и я не могу сделать этого.

Comment: Вы можете оформить ответ,  основываясь на комментариях

Comment: Сделал. Не думал, что администрация такие оформления одобряет.